# Set a undetermined property with a new value of an object through another class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, objective-c-runtime

I have a case where I want to be able to set the value of some property of an object through another class. However:

- I do not know/want to hardcode what property is being set,
- and don't know/want to hardcode the new value of the property

So far I have the class `ValueSetterClass`:

```
class ValueSetterClass<V, T>: NSObject where V: NSObject {

    var item: T?
    private var object: V
    private var key: String

    init(object: V, value: (HELP ME!)) {
        self.object = object
        self.key = #keyPath(value)
        super.init()
    }

    public func setValue() {
        object.setValue(item!, forKey: key)
    }

}
```

where you can initialise the class with the object being changed and the property that should be targeted. Intended to be called like this:

```
let view = UIView()
let valueSetter = ValueSetterClass<UIView, UIColor>(object: view, value: UIView.backgroundColor)
valueSetter.item = .yellow
valueSetter.setValue()
```

However, I cannot figure out what I should place for the type of `value` in the initialiser (where I said `HELP ME!` ☹️)

I know this should work, since you are able to determine the key String of any property:

```
print(#keyPath(UIView.backgroundColor)) // backgroundColor
```

Thanks in advance for help!

PS I'm not crazy, I have a valid reason for wanting to do this!

Comment: Use [`KeyPath`](https://www.klundberg.com/blog/swift-4-keypaths-and-you/) not `#keyPath`

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 solved it. I needed to use Swift 4's new KeyPath instead of #keyPath.

Here's an amended example:

```
class ValueSetterClass<V, T>: NSObject where V: UIView {

    var item: T?
    private var object: V
    private var key: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<V, T>

    init(object: V, key: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<V, T>) {
        self.object = object
        self.key = key
        super.init()
    }

    public func setValue() {
        object[keyPath: key] = item!
    }

}

let view = UIView()
let valueSetter = ValueSetterClass(object: view, key: \.backgroundColor)
valueSetter.item = .yellow
valueSetter.setValue()
```

Thanks!